Divide a large text file into smaller text files when a specific string is detected, but with minimum number of lines
I seek to divide a large text file into smaller text files. Ideally each smaller output text file should have 5 rows, but if the "END" keyword is not present in the 5th row, it should move to next row until it finds the "END" keyword and then create it as one smaller output file.
Example of input text file:
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE CHP GEN'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 20 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE TG1-2 GENS'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 15.5 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-13.2:DEI:TATE-LYLE BTM GENS'
OPEN BUS 249936
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:0.342:DEI:08CR_SOL_GEN:1'
REMOVE MACHINE 1 FROM BUS 251904
END

In this example, 5th row (SET BUS 249831 (...)) does not have "END" keyword, hence it should move to 6th row where there's "END" keyword, and create a small text file of 6 rows, and for next step, it should start from 7th row and follow the same process.
Corresponding expected output:
# file 1
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE CHP GEN'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 20 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE TG1-2 GENS'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 15.5 MW
END

# file 2
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-13.2:DEI:TATE-LYLE BTM GENS'
OPEN BUS 249936
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:0.342:DEI:08CR_SOL_GEN:1'
REMOVE MACHINE 1 FROM BUS 251904
END

My current code creates smaller text files, yet fails the "END" condition:
import glob
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    if file_dir != "":
       os.getcwd()

read_file = glob.glob("*.con")

with open("combined.con", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_file:
        with open (f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
        
df0 = pd.read_csv (file_dir + '/combined.con')```
count = len(df0)
row_range = 5
block = count // row_range
for line in df0:
    for i in range(block):   
        if not line.startswith("END"):
            start = i * row_range
            stop = (i+1) * row_range
            while True:
                row_range = row_range + 1
                df2 = df0.iloc[start:stop]
                df2.to_csv(f"Contingency_{i}.con", index=False)
                break

df0.to_dict() (12 first rows) to reproduce the working dataframe:
{"CONTINGENCY 'P11:069:MPW::MPW 7G-G7:NON-BES'": 
 { 0: 'TRIP BRANCH FROM BUS 633408 TO BUS 633007 CKT 1', 
   1: 'REMOVE UNIT 7 FROM BUS 633007', 
   2: 'DISCONNECT BUS 633007', 
   3: 'END', 
   4: "CONTINGENCY 'P11:069:MPW::MPW 8AG-G8A:NON-BES'", 
   5: 'TRIP BRANCH FROM BUS 633408 TO BUS 633018 CKT 1', 
   6: 'REMOVE UNIT A FROM BUS 633018', 
   7: 'DISCONNECT BUS 633018', 
   8: 'END', 
   9: "CONTINGENCY 'P11:069:MPW::MPW 8G-G8:NON-BES'", 
  10: 'TRIP BRANCH FROM BUS 633408 TO BUS 633008 CKT 1', 
  11: 'REMOVE UNIT 8 FROM BUS 633008'
 }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Previous question: Finding a specific keyword while dividing the large csv into smaller segments, and moving to next row until keyword is found (currently closed)

Honestly, you don't need pandas for this.  It's just causing you trouble.  Just read the file as strings and process the strings.

Formatting your df0.to_dict() into your post (edit submitted) made it appear that you read the first line as column name, which might result in data loss as you write to file. read_csvhas options to prevent that. See: "CONTINGENCY 'P11:069:MPW::MPW 7G-G7:NON-BES'" appears as a column title in the dictionnary you provided.

Attention to exclude the resulting files from the glob, in case you ere to run the code again? That will loop the lines back in for duplicate copies. Either by making the glob more specific, or by writing combined.con to a separate folder.

@OCa Agreed. In case I don't exclude resulting files from the glob, I can't rerun immediately as it appends the newly created files. Thanks for the help!

I saw this question before - but it was closed before I created code.
I don't use pandas, I don't calculate blocks but
I read line by line and add them to list,
and I check if list has 5 or more lines and if there is END as last line.
When list has END and it has 5 or more lines then I write it in file and I clear list.
other_list = []  # list for 5 or more lines
index = 0  # for filename
 
with open("combined.con") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        other_list.append(line)
        if len(other_list) >= 5 and line.startswith('END'):
            with open(f"Contingency_{index}.con", 'w') as outfile:
                for item in other_list:
                    outfile.write(item)
            index += 1
            # clear list
            other_list = []
                   
# make sure there is no data (without `END` in last line)
if len(other_list) > 0:
    with open(f"Contingency_{index}.con", 'w') as outfile:
        for item in other_list:
            outfile.write(item)


Minimal working code.
I use io.StringIO() to create file like object
so I can put example data directly in code.
And everyone can simply copy it for tests.
import io

other_list = []
index = 0

file_like_obj = io.StringIO("""CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE CHP GEN'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 20 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE TG1-2 GENS'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 15.5 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-13.2:DEI:TATE-LYLE BTM GENS'
OPEN BUS 249936
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:0.342:DEI:08CR_SOL_GEN:1'
REMOVE MACHINE 1 FROM BUS 251904
END""")

#with open("combined.con") as infile: 
with file_like_obj as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # skip empty lines
        #if not line.strip():
        #    continue
        other_list.append(line)
        if len(other_list) >= 5 and line.startswith('END'):
            with open(f"Contingency_{index}.con", 'w') as outfile:
                print(f'--- Contingency_{index}.con ---')
                for item in other_list:
                    outfile.write(item)
                    print(item, end='')
            other_list = []
            index += 1
                   
# make sure there is no data (without `END` in last line)
if len(other_list) > 0:
    with open(f"Contingency_{index}.con", 'w') as outfile:
        print(f'--- Contingency_{index}.con ---')
        for item in other_list:
            outfile.write(item)
            print(item, end='')

Result:
--- Contingency_0.con ---
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE CHP GEN'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 20 MW
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-12.47:DEI:PURDUE TG1-2 GENS'
SET BUS 249831 GENERATION TO 15.5 MW
END
--- Contingency_1.con ---
CONTINGENCY 'P11:-13.2:DEI:TATE-LYLE BTM GENS'
OPEN BUS 249936
END
CONTINGENCY 'P11:0.342:DEI:08CR_SOL_GEN:1'
REMOVE MACHINE 1 FROM BUS 251904
END


This code is working. Thank you very much for your help! Really appreciate it @furas
